# Is there a linux monitoring utility for Dell PERC H700?

Tags: centos6, hardware-raid, dell-perc, lsi

I'm looking for a utility to monitor my RAID 5 setup, the card is a Dell PERC H700 with the following chipset:

```
[root@example.net ~]# lspci -v|grep LSI
03:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)
```

The server is a Dell R710. I've been looking around the web but I haven't found concise information yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to install Dell's OpenManage (OMSA) doing the following steps as root:

1.- Install Dell's repos:

```
# wget -q -O - https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi | bash
```

2.- Install all needed RPMs:

```
# yum install srvadmin-all
```

3.- Updated everything (just in case):

```
#yum update
```

4.- Start services and enable them at boot up:

```
# /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh start
 Starting Systems Management Device Drivers:
 Starting dell_rbu:                                         [  OK  ]
 Starting ipmi driver:                                      [  OK  ]
 Starting Systems Management Data Engine:
 Starting dsm_sa_datamgrd:                                  [  OK  ]
 Starting dsm_sa_eventmgrd:                                 [  OK  ]
 Starting DSM SA Shared Services:                           [  OK  ]

 Starting DSM SA Connection Service:                        [  OK  ]

# /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh enable 
 racsvc             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
 instsvcdrv         0:on    1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:on
 dataeng            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
 dsm_om_shrsvc      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
 dsm_om_connsvc     0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
 ipmi               0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

5.-Open port 1311

```
#iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1311 -j ACCEPT //inserts a rule on top
#service iptables save
#service iptables restart
```

6.- Go to: https://sample.test.com:1311

7.- If you get encryption errors:

> Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key

Temporarily downgrade your encryption requirements. For Firefox, type `about:config` in the URL and set `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha` and `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha` to false, login and go to *Preferences>General Settings* and set *SSL Encryption* to *Auto Negotiate*. Now, it works like a charm in other browsers.

Thank you all for pointing me to the right direction.

**EDIT:** Works on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) too, open ports in step 5 accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use MegaRAID tool provide by LSI.

See: http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Dell OpenManage Server Administrator to monitor your PERC and the rest of your Dell hardware

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN266151?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04

Answer (score 2):

I have a PERC H700 installed in a Dell R715 server, running CentOS7.  This is what finally worked for me.  The key reference was [this site](https://www.dokterlinux.id/hardware-raid-setup-using-megacli/).  Specifically, the procedure I followed was:

```
wget –no-check-certificate https://ginernet.com/downloads/MegaCli-8.07.14-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh MegaCli-8.07.14-1.noarch.rpm

alias megacli='/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64'  ## note: you may want to make this a permanent alias by adding to .bashrc

yum install sg3_utils
```

After this, I was able to get the MegaRAID Client working.  But, I needed to operate as the root user in order to do anything useful or get any useful information:

```
sudo -s
```

(simply preceding these commands with `sudo` didn't work)

Finally then, I was able to start doing useful things with the controller.  E.g. to get info about the current RAID configuration:

```
megacli -LDInfo -Lall -a0
```

See if autorebuild is enabled:

```
megacli -AdpAutoRbld -Dsply -a0
```

etc.

The sites [here](https://www.dokterlinux.id/hardware-raid-setup-using-megacli/) and [here](http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS) have a variety of lists of useful commands.